# Generalized function to get indices of array given numerical constraints

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 10x2 numpy array:

```py
>>> array = np.random.randint(0,100,(10,2))
>>> array
array([[ 1, 43],
       [81, 87],
       [92, 46],
       [71, 92],
       [18,  5],
       [98, 25],
       [94, 84],
       [82, 36],
       [75, 83],
       [76, 47]])
```

And I wanted to get the indices of the array that satisfy the following constraints:

```py
>>> bounds = {'min': [5,20], 'max': [80,90]}
```

That is, if I wanted to get the indices where the **first** dimension of `array` is >= 5 AND <=80 AND where the **second** dimension is >= 20 AND <=90, I could do:

```py
>>> np.where((array[:,0] >= bounds['min'][0]) & (array[:,0] <= bounds['max'][0]) 
... & (array[:,1] >= bounds['min'][1]) & (array[:,1] <= bounds['max'][1]))

(array([8, 9]),)
```

How can I generalize the above expression to accommodate an arbitrary number of dimensions (e.g. 10x3, 10x4, etc.)?

Edit: For clarity. I have tried `np.bitwise_and` and `np.logical_and`. However, I get different results depending on how the dimensions are ordered. i.e, my above example returns the same result as:

```py
>>> array_reversed = np.roll(array,1,axis=1)
>>> array_reversed
array([[43,  1],
       [87, 81],
       [46, 92],
       [92, 71],
       [ 5, 18],
       [25, 98],
       [84, 94],
       [36, 82],
       [83, 75],
       [47, 76]])
>>> bounds_reversed = {'min': [20,5], 'max': [90,80]}
>>> np.where((array_reversed[:,0] >= bounds_reversed['min'][0] ) & (array_reversed[:,0] <= bounds_reversed['max'][0])
... & (array_reversed[:,1] >= bounds_reversed['min'][1]) & (array_reversed[:,1] <= bounds_reversed['max'][1]))

(array([8, 9]),)
```

I can't seem to get it to work with `np.bitwise_and` or `np.logical_and`

Comment: `np.logical_and` can operate on a list such boolean tests.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried those functions but it seems to return different results depending on the ordering of the dimensions. See my above edit for clarity

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[ 1, 43],
                  [81, 87],
                  [92, 46],
                  [71, 92],
                  [18,  5],
                  [98, 25],
                  [94, 84],
                  [82, 36],
                  [75, 83],
                  [76, 47]])

bounds = {'min': [5,20], 'max': [80,90]}

lower = np.array(bounds['min'])
upper = np.array(bounds['max'])
np.nonzero(np.all((lower <= array) &  (array <= upper), axis=1))[0]
```

It gives:

```
array([8, 9])
```

It will work with any number of columns.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like this works for all my cases